# Can I get a VertexOpacity-like feature when displaying graphics?

Tags: graphics

I am wondering: why there is no option for `VertexOpacity`, while there is for `VertexColors`?

```
Graphics[Line[Table[{i, 0.02 i}, {i, 1, 5}], VertexColors -> RandomColor[5]]]
```

[image]

I can use `Point`, specifying coloring and opacity, but how I can connect them?

I want this feature to plot 10,000,000 points (or equivalently 4000 lines), and I realize the time consumption of the line is less than Point.

Comment: use `VertexColors  -> MapThread[Append, {RandomColor[5], RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]}]`?

Comment: or `VertexColors -> (Opacity[#, Red] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5])`?

Comment: @kglr, Thanks it seems it works. How can I close this topic?

Comment: If you want, you can write an answer to your own question based on what @kglr wrote, if you understood what he meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prepare the following example based on @kglr comment.

Let's define points as

```
points = Table[{x, y, Cos[2 x] + Cos[2 y]/2}, {x, 0, 10, 0.1}, {y, 0, 10, 0.1}];
```

Now plotting points with separate coloring,

```
Graphics[{Opacity[Abs@#[[3]], 
 Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {0, Yellow}, {1, Red}}, #[[3]]]], 
Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ Flatten[points, 1]]
```

gives,

[image]

using `vertexColors`,

```
Graphics[Point[#[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
VertexColors -> (Opacity[Abs@#, 
     Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {0, Yellow}, {1, Red}}, #]] & /@ #[[All, 
     3]])] & /@ points]
```

gives,

[image]

and if i interpreter it as a line,

```
Graphics[Line[#[[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
VertexColors -> (Opacity[ Abs@#, 
     Blend[{{-1, Blue}, {0, Yellow}, {1, Red}}, #]] & /@ #[[All, 
     3]])] & /@ points]
```

[image]

Comment: To put it another way: if you want to modify the opacity of `Line[]` objects, you can always use colors that have a set alpha channel.